# Cómo corregir este error al acceder al servicio de JasperSoft?

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, jaspersoft

Tengo una página web que sirve para el timbrado de complementos de pago, utiliza el servicio de jaspersoft para elaborar los PDF, solo que de un día para otro dejó de funcionar.
Cuando intento conectarme al servidor desde la aplicación de Jaspersoft me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo o a que se debe dicho error?

Comment: Pues, si debe haber un servicio corriendo en el puerto 8080 y la aplicación dice que Connection refused, hay que revisar los logs de ese servicio porque, o no esta disponible (y por eso no conecta) o alguien en medio no permite las conexiones.

Comment: O cambiaron las credenciales de conexión...

Comment: El puerto 8080 está totalmente libre y las credenciales no han cambiado.

Comment: O sea, si desde una terminal haces telnet localhost 8080, logra conectarse, por ejemplo. Sigue siendo relevante revisar los logs del servicio